# Angular 8 : No changes detected when Toggle button hides a matInput of a form

Tags: angular, angular-material, required

I have a toggle button bind with mode variable on my form, mat-form-fields are visible switchCaes condition basis which is drived from toggleButton value (see code snippet). In matInput-to required validation is also derived from the value of toggle button, I select mode as single, matInput-form is only visiable as expected, but my form is still invalid I dont know why, this should set required false for matInput-to.

mytest.html

```
<shell-panel>
<mat-card-content>
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="this._form.value.mode">
        <div class="mat-card-row">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput required placeholder={{placeHolder}}  maxlength="12" pattern="someRegEx" formControlName="from " />
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-card-row" *ngSwitchCase="'range'">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [required]="this._form.value.mode=='range'" placeholder="to" pattern="someRegEx" formControlName="to" />
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</mat-card-content>                 

<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" formControlName="mode" (click)="resetForm(this._form.value.mode)"  >
    <mat-button-toggle value="single">Single</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="range">Range</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>      

<div class="actions">
    <button mat-fab (click)="onSubmit();" class=".add-button" [disabled]="_form.invalid" matTooltip="Search">
        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

mytest.ts

```
    resetForm(mode: string) {
this._form.controls['mode'].setValue(mode);
this._form.controls['from'].setValue('');
this._form.controls['to'].setValue('');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I can see  you are having reative forms. You can do two things to find what are the fields Which are invalid using the below method. Just pass your formGroup to the below method and console log the output which it returns.

```
public findInvalidControls() {
    const invalid: string[] = [];
    const controls = this._form.controls; 
    for (const name in controls) {
      if (controls[name].invalid) {
        invalid.push(name);
      }
    }
    return invalid;
  }
```

And after adding above method passing it inside to console.log `console.log(this.findInvalidControls())`. You will be able to see the invalid controls accordingly.

Secondly if there is nothing wrong in the console and still if you cannot find out any errors you can update the value and validity of the form from controller in toggle event.
Via this code snippet and try out `this._form.updateValueAndValidity();`